# Custom field outside the loop and inside an array

Tags: custom-field, widgets, loop, array, thumbnails

I am trying to use a **custom field** inside a **widget** so it's therefore outside the loop. Taking it a step further, the theme I have is using an array to generate listings which makes it hard for me to understand.

Basically, the theme uses a **feature image** to display thumbnails of each post and I want to use a **custom field**. Here is the piece of coding I need to change:

```
        <?php if($images && has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
        <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'widget-image'); ?>
        <div class="block-image"><a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' title='<?php the_title(); ?>'><img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width='290' height='160' /></a><?php echo $icon; ?></div>
        <?php else: ?>
        <div class="block-image"><a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' title='<?php the_title(); ?>'><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/thumbnail.png&w=290&h=160" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width='290' height='160' /></a><?php echo $icon; ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

This is inside a counter with an array.

This seems easy enough to do but my programming skills are very limited. I don't know PHP or WordPress very well especially when it comes to outside the loop and using arrays.

I believe I just need to change this line:

```
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'widget-image'); ?>
```

To something like this (but it doesn't work, I think it's because it's outside the loop):

```
<?php $image = get_post_meta($postid, 'Thumbnail', true); ?>
```

**In case you need to see more, here is the entire code on the widget page:**

```
function pyre_homepage_1col_load_widgets()
{
    register_widget('Pyre_Homepage_1col_Widget');
}

class Pyre_Homepage_1col_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    function Pyre_Homepage_1col_Widget()
    {
        $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'pyre_homepage_1col', 'description' => 'Homepage 1-column recent posts widget.');

        $control_ops = array('id_base' => 'pyre_homepage_1col-widget');

        $this->WP_Widget('pyre_homepage_1col-widget', 'Avenue Theme: Home 1-column', $widget_ops, $control_ops);
    }

    function widget($args, $instance)
    {
        extract($args);

        $title = $instance['title'];
        $post_type = 'all';
        $categories = $instance['categories'];
        $posts = $instance['posts'];
        $images = true;
        $rating = true;
        $show_excerpt = isset($instance['show_excerpt']) ? 'true' : 'false';

        echo $before_widget;
        ?>

        <?php
        $post_types = get_post_types();
        unset($post_types['page'], $post_types['attachment'], $post_types['revision'], $post_types['nav_menu_item']);

        if($post_type == 'all') {
            $post_type_array = $post_types;
        } else {
            $post_type_array = $post_type;
        }
        ?>

        <div class="block full">

            <h3><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($categories); ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></a> <span class="arrows">&raquo;</span></h3>

            <?php
            $recent_posts = new WP_Query(array(
                'showposts' => $posts,
                'cat' => $categories,
            ));
            ?>
            <?php
            $big_count = round($posts / 4);
            if(!$big_count) { $big_count = 1; }
            ?>
            <?php $counter = 1; while($recent_posts->have_posts()): $recent_posts->the_post(); ?>
            <?php
            if(has_post_format('video') || has_post_format('audio') || has_post_format('gallery')) {
                $icon = '<span class="' . get_post_format($post->ID) . '-icon"></span>';
            } else {
                $icon = '';
            }
            ?>
            <?php if($counter <= $big_count): ?>
            <?php if($counter == $big_count) { $last = 'block-item-big-last'; } else { $last = ''; }?>
            <div class="block-item-big <?php echo $last; ?>">
                <?php if($images && has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
                <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'widget-image'); ?>
                <div class="block-image"><a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' title='<?php the_title(); ?>'><img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width='290' height='160' /></a><?php echo $icon; ?></div>
                <?php else: ?>
                <div class="block-image"><a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' title='<?php the_title(); ?>'><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/thumbnail.png&w=290&h=160" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width='290' height='160' /></a><?php echo $icon; ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <h2><a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' title='<?php the_title(); ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <span class="block-meta"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?>, <?php comments_popup_link(); ?></span>
                <?php if($show_excerpt == 'true'): ?><p><?php echo string_limit_words(get_the_excerpt(), 15); ?> ...</p><?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <?php else: ?>
            <div class="block-item-small">
                <?php if($images && has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
                <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'widget-image-thumb'); ?>
                <div class="block-image"><a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' title='<?php the_title(); ?>'><img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" width='50' height='50' /></a><?php echo $icon; ?></div>
                <?php else: ?>
                <div class="block-image"><a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' title='<?php the_title(); ?>'><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/thumbnail.png&w=50&h=50" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"  width='50' height='50' /></a><?php echo $icon; ?></div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <h2><a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' title='<?php the_title(); ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <span class="block-meta"><?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?>, <?php comments_popup_link(); ?></span>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php $counter++; endwhile; ?>

        </div>

        <?php
        echo $after_widget;
    }

    function update($new_instance, $old_instance)
    {
        $instance = $old_instance;

        $instance['title'] = $new_instance['title'];
        $instance['post_type'] = 'all';
        $instance['categories'] = $new_instance['categories'];
        $instance['posts'] = $new_instance['posts'];
        $instance['show_images'] = true;
        $instance['show_rating'] = true;
        $instance['show_excerpt'] = $new_instance['show_excerpt'];

        return $instance;
    }

    function form($instance)
    {
        $defaults = array('title' => 'Recent Posts', 'post_type' => 'all', 'categories' => 'all', 'posts' => 4, 'show_excerpt' => null);
        $instance = wp_parse_args((array) $instance, $defaults); ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>">Title:</label>
            <input class="widefat" style="width: 216px;" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('categories'); ?>">Filter by Category:</label> 
            <select id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('categories'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('categories'); ?>" class="widefat categories" style="width:100%;">
                <option value='all' <?php if ('all' == $instance['categories']) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>all categories</option>
                <?php $categories = get_categories('hide_empty=0&depth=1&type=post'); ?>
                <?php foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
                <option value='<?php echo $category->term_id; ?>' <?php if ($category->term_id == $instance['categories']) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $category->cat_name; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('posts'); ?>">Number of posts:</label>
            <input class="widefat" style="width: 30px;" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('posts'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('posts'); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['posts']; ?>" />
        </p>

        <p>
            <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" <?php checked($instance['show_excerpt'], 'on'); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('show_excerpt'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('show_excerpt'); ?>" /> 
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('show_excerpt'); ?>">Show excerpt</label>
        </p>
    <?php }
}
?>
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: The piece of code you posted is inside a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a custom field value outside of the loop you need to call `global $wp_query` to get your post id.

```
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
$image = get_post_meta($postid, 'Thumbnail', true);
```

Comment: You can also use `get_queried_object_id()` to grab IDs.  But it's not going to be a post id on all pages on the site.

Comment: Looking at the sample code it looks like the code in question is actually inside a loop, `$post->ID` should be fine(as is referenced elsewhere inside the loop as it currently stands).

Comment: Okay so I tried replacing `<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'widget-image'); ?>`with this piece of code `<?php $image = get_post_meta($postid, 'Thumbnail', true); ?>` but when I test it the img src is still empty.

This is what the img src looks like `<img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />`

Comment: Furthermore, when I try putting this code in `<?php global $wp_query; $postid = $wp_query->post->ID; $image = get_post_meta($postid, 'Thumbnail', true); ?>
<?php print_r($image); ?>`

@ChristopherDavis @MarkDuncan

Print_r outputs the $image as a url to the last block-item-big in the array loop. What I don't understand is that it does output a url path (even though it may be the wrong one) the img src does not display it properly with `<img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />`